# Incorrect for loop solution in django app

Tags: python, django, templates, for-loop

I have a page with objects in django application. I display it on using a for loop. I want to do something like that if the loop is at 5 cycle, I want to appear to the new page. I need this to generate the pdf file.
On each site I want to have only 5 objects. But this solutions below is not working for me.

```
<table width="90%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <h3>{% trans 'In progress' %}</h3>
    {% for worked_on in worker.worked_on.all %}
        <tr>
            <td width="33%" align="left" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
            <td width="67%" class="project-name">
                <a href="#">{{ translated_project.title }}</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="project-image" width="33%" align="left" valign="top">
                // CONTENT
            </td>
            <td class="project-description" valign="top">
                // CONTENT
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p>
                {% if forloop.counter == 5 %}
                    <div style="page-break-after: always;"></div>
                {% endif %}
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`divisibleby`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#divisibleby) template filter:

```
{% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:"5" %}
    <div style="page-break-after: always;"></div>
{% endif %}
```